# Why excluding the end points in Short Calculus?

Tags: calculus, functions

I’m reading a book about calculus **Short Calculus by serge lang**.

I’ve realized that the author always excludes the end points while talking about the existence of maxima and minima or the mean value theorem .

Is this something related to these theorem or it is just the choice of the author?

Comment: It's often important to the theorem, since things can happen at the endpoints that can't happen in the interior. Consider asking about a specific example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very useful not to require differentiability at the endpoints. Consider [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) (a special case of the mean value theorem) applied to the function $f : [-1, 1] \to [0, 1]$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ (so the graph is a semicircle). $f$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$ and differentiable on $(-1, 1)$, so we can apply Rolle's theorem, even though $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ or $1$, to conclude that $f'(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (-1, 1)$.